# Angular 5 how to handle HTML received from backend

Tags: angular

I am receiving an HTML(with Facebook login) from my back-end but the observable tries to parse it before I have any chance to do anything with it... I can't explain my problem to google, so even the professional terms of what I am trying to do, would be a great help...

Comment: if your back-end is delivering the html, maybe you can wrap it and deliver it as JSON instead {"myHtmlObject":"<html>....</html>"}

Comment: Could you try to describe your question more in details (maybe post the relevant part of your code)?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `responseType` in your request method

```
this.http.post(url, body, { responseType: 'text' });
```

By default responseType is json and Angular try to parse it